# How do I configure Intern 4 to use RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, intern

I've got RequireJS installed in my node_modules directory, and my intern.json file has:

```
"node": {
    "loader": "requirejs"
},
```

However, when I run "npx intern", it fails with:

> Error: Loader script requirejs did not register a loader callback
>     at 
>     at

Is there a way to get Intern 4 to use RequireJS?

Answer (score 1):

To use a particular loader, Intern needs a 'loader' script that will actually initialize the loader and handle loading modules with it. Intern includes loader scripts for several loaders, such as Dojo 1, Dojo, and SystemJS. It doesn't include a loader script for RequireJS, but you can add one fairly easily.

A simple script for RequireJS would look like:

```js
// your_project/reqjs.js
intern.registerLoader(function(options) {
  function initLoader(requirejs) {
    // Configure requireJS -- use options passed in through the intern.json
    // config, and add anything else
    requirejs.config(options);

    // This is the function Intern will actually call to load modules
    return function(modules) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        requirejs(modules, function() {
          resolve();
        }, function(error) {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    };
  };

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return intern
      .loadScript('node_modules/requirejs/require.js')
      .then(function() {
        return initLoader(window.requirejs);
      });
  } else {
    return initLoader(require('requirejs'));
  }
});
```

Note that Intern doesn't use loaders to actually retrieve modules for its own use (which is why the `resolve` call above doesn't include the loaded modules), it only uses them to load test suites. The suites themselves may use the loader normally.

You would use the script in your config with

```
"node": {
  "loader": "./reqjs.js"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks good although probably needs to be tweaked a bit for the browser client on IE11, where Promise isn't defined?

Comment: Also, when running from node, there's no variable called `global`, and although there is a global variable called `require` it's node's built-in `require()` method, not the one from RequireJS.

Comment: Intern loads a Promise polyfill in the browser, so you should be good there. Regarding `global`, that's Node's equivalent to `window` -- it should always be available. Regarding `require`, it appears that requirejs doesn't set a global in a Node context (it's been a while since I used RequireJS in Node), so you'll need to import require in a different way in Node. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that looks better although presumably still doesn't work on IE because it's using ES6 syntax.  But I did something similar in https://github.com/wkeese/intern-requirejs-example that's working.

Comment: Oops; IE supports `const`, but I forgot about that arrow function. I updated the code to be more IE friendly. In any case, glad to hear you got something working!